# CPU a tope en DigitalOcean

Tags: php, wordpress, centos, digitalocean

ultimamente he tenido tenido picos que elevan el CPU al 100% en mi droplet de DigitalOcean, tengo la leve sospecha de que algún proceso dentro de mi wordpress se queda ciclado ya que entro al servidor y ejecutar el comando top -c y veo muchas peticiones php, cabe destacar que el droplet tiene una capacidad de 16 GB de RAM 320 de SSD y está montado sobre centosOS 7

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También anexo una imagen de la carga del cpu en digital ocean,
de antemano agradesco su ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes instalar `htop` mostrarnos los datos? Del mismo modo, ¿tienes la opción de instalar y configurar PHP-FPM? Eso te permitirá ver también mucho mejor los procesos.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responder, pero ya se optó por hacer hacer otra instalacion en un servidor nuevo, hasta el dia de hoy la página se mantiene muy estable al igual que el nuevo servidor.